# Mineflayer bot for Python, logging out of the server using a third-party file

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, minecraft, mineflayer

I am writing a mineflayer bot via Python:

```
mineflayer = require('mineflayer')

bot_minecraft = mineflayer.createBot({
            'host': host,
            'username': username,
            'version': False

    })

@On(bot_minecraft, 'login')
    def logined(*args):
        print("spawn")
```

I have a file where the input() command is executed by the while loop:

```
while True:
    input()
```

I need my bot to exit the server by entering the quit command here. What can be done?